# Elasticsearch-Java Search is not giving any results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Just started off with ElasticSearch and JAVA Client APIs today itself and trying with a very simple Hello World program. However when i am trying to search the document for a particular keyword, i am not getting any results.

Need some help here -

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().clusterName("elasticsearch").node();
Client client = node.client();
client.prepareIndex("kodcucom", "article", "1")
                .setSource(putJsonDocument("Anurag",
                        "ElasticSeach provides Java API, thus it executes all operations "
                                + "asynchronously by using client object..",
                        new Date(), new String[] { "elasticsearch" }, "Anurag Jain"))
                .execute().actionGet();

client.prepareIndex("kodcucom", "article", "2")
                .setSource(putJsonDocument("Java Web Application and ElasticSearch (Video)",
                        "Today, here I am for exemplifying the usage of ElasticSearch which is an open source, distributed "
                                + "and scalable full text search engine and a data analysis tool in a Java web application.",
                        new Date(), new String[] { "elasticsearch" }, "Saanchi Jain"))
                .execute().actionGet();
```

PutJsonDocument method -

```
public static Map<String, Object> putJsonDocument(String title, String content, Date postDate, String[] tags,
            String author) {

        Map<String, Object> jsonDocument = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        jsonDocument.put("title", title);
        jsonDocument.put("content", content);
        jsonDocument.put("postDate", postDate);
        jsonDocument.put("tags", tags);
        jsonDocument.put("author", author);

        return jsonDocument;
    }
```

This is putting the documents in ES as the getDocuments are giving me the results.

However searching the documents is not working for me -

```
public static void searchDocument(Client client, String index, String type, String field, String value) {

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(field, value))
                .setFrom(0).setSize(60)
                .setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();

        System.out.println("Current results: " + results.length);
        for (SearchHit hit : results) {
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            Map<String, Object> result = hit.getSource();
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

This is how its being called -

```
searchDocument(client, "kodcucom", "article", "title", "Anurag");
```

Output is -

```
Current results: 0
```

Now my goal is simple that i just want to search the title field for a keyword say "Anurag" and return the corresponding document. Any advice/pointers?

BR,

Anurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `title` field is an `analyzed` string by default. If you search for `anurag` in lowercase, you'll get a match.

```
searchDocument(client, "kodcucom", "article", "title", "anurag");
                                                        ^
                                                        |
                                                use lowercase here
```

Comment: Also just added the putJsonDocument method code as well in my question.

Comment: Weird, can you also add the mapping type you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/kodcucom/_mapping/article`?

Comment: {"kodcucom":{"mappings":{"article":{"properties":{"author":{"type":"string"},"c
ntent":{"type":"string"},"postDate":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_option
l_time||epoch_millis"},"tags":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}}}}

Comment: How many results do you get with `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/kodcucom/article/_search -d '{"query":{"term":{"title":"anurag"}}}'` ?

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xco
ntent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed",
"phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"kodcucom","n
ode":"ay_UH5QjSVG8K8wtCTM7vw","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Faile
d to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400}

Comment: Also just FYI, i dont have any previous experience with elastic search, so dont know if i am doing my basics wrong here

Comment: Weird. How about just this (basic search, no constraints) `curl -XGET localhost:9200/kodcucom/article/_search` How many results do you get?

Comment: {"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hit
s":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"kodcucom","_type":"article","_i
d":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{"tags":["elasticsearch"],"content":"Today, here I
 am for exemplifying the usage of ElasticSearch which is an open source, distrib

Truncated....rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101648/discussion-between-val-and-aj84).

Comment: and thanks a ton for a great help....this worked ...and thanks for the 
client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().get(); suggestion

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running `Elasticsearch` indexing and searching API's on the same JAVA program sequentially, there is not enough time for `Elasticsearch` index to be refreshed with your new indexed json document.

By default, `Elasticsearch` will call refresh periodically every 1 second.
JAVA code (as you know) run faster than the time it took `Elasticsearch` to prepare the document for searching and  therefore it didn't return your document.

One way to solve it is to `Thread.sleep(2000);` before searching (which is a very bad practice but for learning the API it would work).

Another way to solve it, is by using `prepareRefresh()` before searching:
`client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().get();`
Which forces `Elasticsearch` to refresh its indexes and be ready for consecutive search requests.

Comment: I would agree with this answer along with what Val suggested above that "lowercase" should be used. Together its the perfectly complete answer...Thanks guys